# How do I update subscription variables in a useSubscription hook - Apollo v3

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

I am currently trying to update a GraphQL subscription using the useSubscription hook from apollo v3 in a useEffect hook:

```js
let containerSubscription = useSubscription<CreatedDateSubscription, CreatedDateSubscriptionVariables>(
  gql(containerUpdatedOnCreatedDate),
  {
    variables: { createdDate: selectedDate },
    shouldResubscribe: true, // is this needed?
  },
);

// update subscription on date change
React.useEffect(() => {
  // how do I update the subscription here?
  // setting containerSubscription.variables = ... does not change the subscription
}, [selectedDate]);
```

I could not find any solution in the apollo docs on how to address this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you're not supposed to do that, I didn't find any documentation on that either, perhaps because you need to unsubscribe and resubscribe with new variables

Comment: @Arman thank you, I thought about that. But then, I could find any documentation on how to unsubscribe and resubscribe in the docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use `useEffect` -- you just need to change `selectedDate`. If any of the options passed to the hook change, the current subscription will be unsubscribed and a new one will be started using the new options.

Comment: Didn't think about that, thank you! It finally worked when i omitted the `shouldResubscribe` option